# I need to hold multiple int values in a Map

Tags: java, list, dictionary, integer

I need to create a book index method which can pair multiple values to one key

e.g
key - "Beck,Kent"
value - 27 23 76

is this possible?

the import ou.*; is the Open University library and should not affect anything.

```
import java.util.*;
import ou.*;
public class BookIndex
{

public Map<String, Integer> index()
{
   Map<String, Integer> actual = new HashMap<>();
   return actual;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How about using an integer array instead of an Integer in `Map<String, Integer>`.

```
 HashMap<String, Integer[]> anewMap = new HashMap<String, Integer[]>();

 anewMap.put("Beck,Kent",new Integer[] { 27, 23, 76});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make and object to store instead of the Integer that holds the int values.

```
Map<String, YourObject> actual = new HashMap<>();
```

If you could be more specific about things I could show you what that class might look like. In your example you would use the KEY "Beck,Kent" to search for the values with the function get(), this is as much help as I can give currently

Comment: Thanks! i need to create the map and then be able to search for keys via values. so if you ask for all names appearing between pages 10-20 they are returned.

Comment: I think your mixing things up, you use the key to search for the value not the other way around

Comment: i did think it was odd. question asks: method should return all of the names occurring within a given page range

Comment: Hmm not so sure I understand what you need, It seems like there is more to this question than u are stating

Comment: yeah sorry, i don't really want to post the question verbatim andrisk getting pulled up for cheating or anything. thanks for your help though!